# Detect Android Quick Settings Panel swipe down in JS - Browser

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript

**Background**

I'm working on an Angular Web-App that's used to control a device using a Gamepad.

**The Problem**

We have come across an edge case, where the Gamepad API essentially responds with a stuck state if the user swipes down or accesses the Android "Quick Settings Panel".

This can cause a run-away condition, if the operator drags down the panel while providing gamepad input. This is because I cannot distinguish between prolonged unchanging inputs (full stick forward) and the stuck state due to swipe down as the Gamepad API does not update Gamepad.timestamp unless an axis or button value changes.

- You can see the that behaviour in GamepadTester

**Attempted Remedies**

I tried multiple ways to detect that the browser is behind the menu:

- window.onblur
- addEventListener("blur", (
- checking !document.hasFocus() in a timer loop

I can reliably detect that a the operator switches to another app or goes to the home-screen. However the Android Quick Settings Panel remains undetected.

**Other solutions looked into:**

All in the snippet.

```js
var elementBtnFullScreen = document.getElementById("btnFullScreen");  
elementBtnFullScreen.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
});


  
var logText="";
var elementTALog = document.getElementById("log");

var elementBlurWindow = document.getElementById("blurWindow");
window.onblur = () => {
  elementBlurWindow.innerHTML = "Detected: " + Date.now();
}

var elementBlurTimer = document.getElementById("blurTimer");
setInterval(() => {
  if (!document.hasFocus()) {
        elementBlurTimer.innerHTML = "Detected: " + Date.now();
    }
}, 200);


var elementBlurEvent = document.getElementById("blurEvent");
var elementFocusOutEvent = document.getElementById("focusOutEvent");

addEventListener("blur", () => { elementBlurEvent.innerHTML = "Detected: " + Date.now(); });
addEventListener("focusout", () => { elementFocusOutEvent.innerHTML = "Detected: " + Date.now(); });


// - Other Tests -----
addEventListener("compositionend", (event) => { log("compositionend", event) });
addEventListener("compositionstart", (event) => { log("compositionstart", event) });
addEventListener("compositionupdate", (event) => { log("compositionupdate", event) });
addEventListener("dragleave", (event) => { log("dragleave", event) });
addEventListener("dragover", (event) => { log("dragover", event) });
addEventListener("dragend", (event) => { log("dragend", event) });
addEventListener("drag", (event) => { log("drag", event) });
addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => { log("dragstart", event) });
addEventListener("dragenter", (event) => { log("dragenter", event) });
addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => { log("mouseleave", event) });
addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => { log("mouseout", event) });
addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => { log("mousemove", event) });
addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => { log("mouseover", event) });
addEventListener("pointerout", (event) => { log("pointerout", event) }); // No good - since it triggers if people swipe across screen

addEventListener("pointermove", (event) => { log("pointermove", event) });  // No good - since it triggers if people swipe across screen
addEventListener("pointerover", (event) => { log("pointerover", event) }); // No good - since it triggers if people swipe across screen
addEventListener("pointerup", (event) => { log("pointerup", event) });
addEventListener("pointerleave", (event) => { log("pointerleave", event) });
addEventListener("lostpointercapture", (event) => { log("lostpointercapture", event) }); // No good - since it triggers 
addEventListener("gotpointercapture", (event) => { log("gotpointercapture", event) });

addEventListener("change", (event) => { log("change", event) });
addEventListener("animationend", (event) => { log("animationend", event) });
addEventListener("animationiteration", (event) => { log("animationiteration", event) });
addEventListener("animationstart", (event) => { log("animationstart", event) });
addEventListener("animationcancel", (event) => { log("animationcancel", event) });
addEventListener("webkitanimationiteration", (event) => { log("webkitanimationiteration", event) });
addEventListener("webkittransitionend", (event) => { log("webkittransitionend", event) });
addEventListener("webkitanimationstart", (event) => { log("webkitanimationstart", event) });




function log(eventName, event) {
    var line =  eventName + " | " + Date.now() + " | ";
    line = append(line, event.x, "x");
  line = append(line, event.y, "y");
  line = append(line, event.clientX, "clientX");
  line = append(line, event.clientY, "clientY");
  line = append(line, event.screenX, "screenX");
  line = append(line, event.screenY, "screenY");
  
  
  logText = line + "\n" + logText;
  elementTALog.innerHTML = logText;
}

function append(line, property, propertyName) {
    if (property !== null && property !== undefined) {
        var propertyOut = property;
        
        if (typeof property === 'number') {
            propertyOut = Math.round(property * 100) / 100;
        }
    
    return line += propertyName + ": " + propertyOut + ", ";
  }
}
```

```css
      textarea {
          width: 100%;
          height: 250px;
        }
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
      <title>Event Tester</title>

    </head>
        
    <body>
    
    <button id="btnFullScreen">Enter Fullscreen</button>
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Blurr Detections</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Window</td>
        <td id="blurWindow"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Timer</td>
        <td id="blurTimer"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>BlurEvent</td>
        <td id="blurEvent"></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>FocusOut Event</td>
        <td id="focusOutEvent"></td>
      </tr>  
    </table>
    

  <textarea id="log"></textarea>
    
    
    </body>


</html>
```